# how to set the default value from view in sap.m.multiComboBox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
<MultiComboBox id="empDropDown" items="{/emp}" 
                        selectedKeys="{/emp/0/empNumber}">
                            <core:Item key="{empNumber}" text="{Name}" />
                        </MultiComboBox>
```

The data is directly bound to data in the model in the following format:
{
    "empNumber": 8683,
    "Name": "A001",
    "Description": "Description 1",
}

Comment: And what exactly do you want to show in the multiComboBox? 8683 & A001 & Description 1 at once?

Answer (score 2):

As I did not understood exactly what you want to get I did simple example in the xml:

```
<MultiComboBox id="comboBoxTest" selectedKeys="key0,key1" width="150px">
   <core:Item id="idName1" text="A000" key="key0" />
   <core:Item id="idName2" text="A001" key="key1" />
   <core:Item id="idName3" text="A002" key="key2" />
   <core:Item id="idName4" text="A003" key="key3" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

And also I did similar working example for the controller in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gizifuhaxa/1/edit?html,js,output) as different approach.

```
var mData = {
  items:[  
    {key:"0",name:"A000"},  
    {key:"1",name:"A001"},  
    {key:"2",name:"A002"},  
    {key:"3",name:"A003"}  
  ]  
};
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(mData); //set data here
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "ComboBoxData");

var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({  
  key : "{key}",  
  text : "{name}"  
}); 

var mcb = new sap.m.MultiComboBox({  
  id : "mcb",  
  items : {  
    path : "/items",  
    template : oItemTemplate,     
  }
});
mcb.setModel(oModel);

//here you can select pre chosen values, for example [0,1] first two names are chosen
mcb.setSelectedKeys([0,1]);

mcb.placeAt('content');
```